# Merging vertical with slightly larger horizontal cylinder properly without creating Ngons?

Tags: modeling

I have a question.

I am trying to find a way to merge a horizontal and vertical cylinder, and have a bevel on the edge where they end up merging.
I tried this with a boolean cutting a hole in one of the cylinders, then merge the objects and bridge the faces of the 2 different cylinders together. But I can't manage to do that without creating a whole bunch of Ngons or distorting the shape. Any method to properly do this?

This is the result I managed to get so far.

[image]

Comment: Maybe show some screenshots. Once you have ngons you can bring some corrections.

Comment: Thanks, I made an example of what I am trying to do and added it to the post, but have not managed to do it properly.

Comment: It is not too bad, to avoid the triangles you could use more vertical edge loops. But do you need so many faces? It would be easy to work with less, use a Subsurf to make it smooth, and apply the modifier at the end if necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Use the knife tool <kbd>k</kbd> to add these loops, while dissolving the one you already had and the triangle.

[image: New loops]

Remember to use <kbd>c</kbd> for 45 degree cuts and <kbd>z</kbd> to cut through to both sides.

Ideally when using cylinders I work with no more than 16 verts or it gets very messy and hard to keep the shape if you need loops to run parallel.

Comment: this helped quite a bit, also added the subsurface moonboots was talking about.
It's not perfect, but definitely looks way better. Thanks.

Comment: try to work with less edge loops if they are not necessary, so begin with more low-poly cylinder

Comment: @eastbound - if this answer solved your problem, instead of "Thanks", please mark it as "[accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)"

Comment: @metaphor_set sorry about that, I am new to this community. I Marked the answer.